# SystemExit: 2 error with the parser.parse_args() in Jupiter note

Tags: python, argparse

I am learning how to scrape YouTube comments to perform a sentimental analysis. Unfortunately, as I ran the code, I received an error. How can I fix this issue? And if you could give me a clear explanation of what I did wrong, that would be great.

Code:

```
def youtube_video_url(options):
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey = key)
   
    search_response = youtube.search().list(q = options.q, part = "id,snippet", maxResults = options.max_results).execute() 
    
    for search_result in search_response.get("items", []): 
        if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
            print("VideoId: " +str(videoId)) # it only contain the url ID not the entire url, which you have to append it with the url alias below.
            videoIds.append(videoId)
            url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoId 
            print(url)
    return url



# taking the movie name as input 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print( "Enter the Movie Name : ")
    Movie_name = str(input())
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "youtube search") 
    parser.add_argument("--q", required = True, help = "Search term", default = Movie_name + "Movie Trailer 2021") 
    parser.add_argument("--max-results", required = True, help = "Max results", default = 1) # First link
   
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    youtube_video_url = youtube_video_url(args) 
    scrape_comments(youtube_video_url, Movie_name)
```

Error message:

```
Enter the Movie Name : 
Spider-Man Trailer
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] --q Q --max-results MAX_RESULTS
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: --q, --max-results
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

Used %tb to get detail

```
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-413a90992e30> in <module>()
    108     parser.add_argument("--max-results", "--image", help = "Max results", default = 1) # First link
    109     # --max-results => is giving 1 (defualt = 1) which mean it will return one particular link only
--> 110     args = parser.parse_args()
    111     # Call Youtube search method and pass this combined argument
    112     youtube_video_url = youtube_video_url(args) # The url of the top link will come

2 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/argparse.py in exit(self, status, message)
   2502         if message:
   2503             self._print_message(message, _sys.stderr)
-> 2504         _sys.exit(status)
   2505 
   2506     def error(self, message):

SystemExit: 2
```

Comment: You did wrong that you told your program to ask for command line arguments `--q` and `--max-results` but then didn't provide those arguments when running the program.

Comment: You can fix it by either not requiring the arguments, or by providing them.

Comment: using `argparse` with a notebook is difficult.  That input is designed for scripts run from the shell directly.

Comment: I assume this code is copied from someone else, may be a tutorial?  Didn't they provide instructions?  are you actually following them?

Comment: Got it! Thank you, guys so much. I have fixed that and now I got an error stating the string index out of range.

Comment: Yes, from a tutorial. I did, but some parts of the explanation weren't there, or maybe I just didn't understand. I followed every step and also took notes on the explanation.